# value _2 is not a member of Double spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am getting an error while implementing aggregateByKey in spark-scala-shell.

The piece of code that I am trying to execute on Scala-shell is this,

```
val orderItemsMapJoinOrdersMapMapAgg = orderItemsMapJoinOrdersMapMap
  .aggregateByKey(0.0,0)(
      (a,b) => (a._1 + b , a._2 + 1),
      (a,b) => (a._1 + b._1 , a._2 + b._2 )
  )
```

But I am getting the following error,

```
<console>:39: error: value _1 is not a member of Double
         val orderItemsMapJoinOrdersMapMapAgg = orderItemsMapJoinOrdersMapMap.aggregateByKey( 0.0,0)( (a,b) => (a._1 + b , a._2 +1), (a,b) => (a._1 + b._1 , a._2 + b._2 ))


scala> orderItemsMapJoinOrdersMapMap
res8: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Float)] = MapPartitionsRDD[16] at map at <console>:37
```

Can  someone help me in understanding double and Float value logic and how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are providing the first curried argument the wrong way. It should be something like this,

```
val orderItemsMapJoinOrdersMapMap: RDD[(String, Float)] = ...

// so elems of your orderItemsMapJoinOrdersMapMap are (String, Float)

// And your accumulator looks like (Double, Int)

// thus I believe that you just want to accumulate total number of elements and sum of the floats in them

val orderItemsMapJoinOrdersMapMapAgg = orderItemsMapJoinOrdersMapMap
  .aggregateByKey((0.0,0))(
      (acc, elem) => (acc._1 + elem._2 , acc._2 + 1),
      (acc1, acc2) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1 , acc1._2 + acc._2)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you @Sarvesh Kumar Singh for quick and nice response.
I want to know about why i got output Rdd of type  RDD[(String,  (Double, Int))]  instead of RDD[(String,  (Float, Int))]  as i have used toFloat in earlier map operation

Comment: `0.0` is not a `Float`. If you want `Float` then you can use `0.0f`.

Comment: Thanks @Sarvesh Kumar Singh